# BeginInvokeOnMainThread not finishing the task

Tags: c#, xamarin

How can we make `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` wait until the process is completed ?

Without getting  `something` it goes to the `Method(something)`;

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    something = await SomeFunction();
                });
Method(something);
```

Comment: Why do you want begin invoke on main thread to wait for this task?

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend that you reconsider your design. Background threads should not be reaching out to the UI thread or scheduling work onto it. Consider inverting this control and make the UI thread be the boss. You can use `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>` for progress updates, or if you are in the rare situation where there are unrequested updates from background threads, you can se a `SynchronizationContext`.

However, if you really want to use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, it is *possible*. There are two problems: `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` takes an `Action` argument (and thus you must be careful with `async` delegates), and `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` returns `void`, so getting a result value from that method is difficult.

That said, you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to force this to work:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SomeFunctionReturnType>();
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
  try { tcs.TrySetResult(await SomeFunction()); }
  catch (Exception ex) { tcs.TrySetException(ex); }
});
Method(await tcs.Task);
```